# Selecting one row with different conditions

Tags: php, sql

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Nis.png]

Hi, I tried to get the result table from 3 other tables using SQL query but I could not achieve it. I am sure its possible to arrive the result table. Please help me to achieve the result

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Please include the code/query that you tried, sample input, desired output, and the actual/current/undesired result _in the body of the question_.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 3 joins, and have to rename the table `locations` because it appears twice:

```
SELECT routes.id, src.title, dest.title, groups.title FROM routes 
  INNER JOIN locations as src ON (src.id = routes.src)
  INNER JOIN locations as dest ON (dest.id = routes.dest)  
  INNER JOIN groups ON (groups.id = routes.groups)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I am getting src, dest and group but i am not get id in result column..

Comment: SELECT routes.id, src.title, dest.title, groups.title FROM routes
  INNER JOIN locations as src ON (src.id = routes.src)
  INNER JOIN locations as dest ON (dest.id = routes.dest)  
  INNER JOIN groups ON (groups.id = routes.groups) order by routes.id

Comment: I modified the query.